Good practice Beamer presentation
after a few presentations, I would like to improve myself. Attached is a short presentation. I look forward to suggestions for improvement.
Maybe i should use blocks instead of description?
Thank you! Patrick
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}


\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}       %für logische Symbole
\usepackage{systeme}                %für Gleichungssysteme
\usepackage{multicol}               %für mehrere Spalten

%\usepackage{longtable}             %für Tabellen mit Seitenumbruch
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\newcommand{\E}{\text{\euro}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{wrapfig2}%um Bilder neben dem Text zu plazieren
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{geometry}





\definecolor{ETSrot}{cmyk}{0,.91,1,0.2}
\definecolor{ETSgrau}{cmyk}{ 0.47, 0.35, 0.32,0.18}
\definecolor{ETSschwarz}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 1}


\usecolortheme[named=ETSrot]{structure}

\title{Brandschutzhelferschulung}
\subtitle{DGUV}
\author{Der Sicherheitsbeauftragte}
\institute{Edertalschule}
\date{\today}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}}%logo

%\areaset{24cm}{16cm}


\begin{document}
\titlepage


\section{Offizielles}
\begin{frame}{Aufgaben}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1->Brände verhüten!
        \item<2->Brände melden!
        \item<3->Personen retten!
        \item<4->Gebäude evakuieren
        \item<4->Brände bekämpfen
        \item<4->Zusammenarbeit mit Feuerwehr
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\section{Feuer / Brand}
\begin{frame}{Technische Einrichtung}
    \begin{block}{kein Feuer, kein Rauch}
        \lipsum[1][2]
    \end{block}
    \begin{description}
        \item[Vorbeugender Brandschutz]\only<2,9->{ Brandlasten reduzieren! Bauliche Ma\ss nahmen}
        \item[Brandabschnitt]\only<3,9->{ höchstens 35m / Umgang}
        \item[Bekämpfungsmittel] \only<4,9->{Markierung, Umgang und Funktion}   
        \item[Brandmelder / Rauchmelder] \only<5,9->{Markierung, ,Umgang und Funktion}
        \item[Rettungswege] \only<6,9->{Markieren / Bekannt machen / frei halten}
        \item[Sammelplätze] \only<7,9->{Markieren / Bekannt machen / frei halten}
    \end{description}   
\end{frame}





\begin{frame}%{Allgemeines}
    \begin{description}
        \item<1-> [Brände verhüten!]
        \item<2>[Brände melden!] \alert<2>{Ihr,}  und den SuS erläutern.
        \item<-3>[Personen retten] Für besondere Personen.
        \item [Gebäude evakuieren]\textcolor<3>{green}{grün} und noch ein Test
        \item [Brände bekämpfen]
        \item [Zusammenarbeit mit Feuerwehr]
    \end{description}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image-duck}
        \caption[Icon]{Im Schulportal findet man hier alle Informationen}
        \label{fig:Icon Sicherheit}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


You most likely don't need multirow. Most often tables turn out more clear with simple top alignment for shared cells (and instead a bit more space between the next cell-region -- see booktabs and its documentation).

Instead of \caption{...}\label{...} use \caption{...\label{...}} (just make sure not to put a space in front of the \label).

You don't need lipsum in any real presentation (there might be a very small number of presentations needing it world wide).

@Skillmon  ... and for the handful of presentation which need dummy text, duckuments is much more fun than boring lipsum :P


you don't need \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}, \usepackage{hyperref}, \usepackage{graphicx}, \usepackage{geometry} - beamer loads them automatically

\usepackage{multicol} is usually not necessary, use beamer columns instead

\usepackage{wrapfig2}: if a slide has so much text that you can wrap it around an image, it has too much text. Instead position text and image side by side using columns.

\date{\today} is not necessary - that's the default

35m: use siunitx to get proper spacing between values and units

\centering isn't necessary, figures are automatically centred in beamer

instead of \begin{frame}{...} better use \begin{frame}\frametitle{...}. That's more robust and flexible.

Ma\ss: given that you somehow managed to input all the umlauts, you can also use Maß


